# Unable to ssh to one of my VM's

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos-7

I have just build 4 VM's much identical to each other but I not sure as to why for one VM I am not able to ssh from SecureCRT.

Host OS is Windows 10 All Four VM as CentOS(two Centos 6.8 and two Centos 7)

All four can do ssh to each other.

I am stuck with what I need to do to get it fixed. Port 22 is opened on all four VM's.

I tried to do telnet for each machine IP from cmd(windows) and for the one which is having issue it says: C:\WINDOWS\system32>telnet 192.168.1.4 22 Connecting To 192.168.1.4...Could not open connection to the host, on port 22: Connect failed C:\WINDOWS\system32> ssh is open on the host for sure then I why I get this message? –

Confused and not sure what I need to do to get it fixed.

```
[root@agent2 ~]# iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
   23  1575 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   75 11903 INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   75 11903 INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   75 11903 INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3   252 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   70 11531 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 27 packets, 3669 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
   55  8531 OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  enp0s3 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      enp0s3  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   66 10104 IN_public  all  --  enp0s3 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    9  1799 IN_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   75 11903 IN_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   75 11903 IN_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   75 11903 IN_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
[root@agent2 ~]# 

[root@puppet ~]# ss -lntp
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                                       Local Address:Port                                         Peer Address:Port 
LISTEN      0      5                                                       :::5666                                                   :::*      users:(("nrpe",3398,5))
LISTEN      0      5                                                        *:5666                                                    *:*      users:(("nrpe",3398,4))
LISTEN      0      128                                                     :::111                                                    :::*      users:(("rpcbind",1454,11))
LISTEN      0      128                                                      *:111                                                     *:*      users:(("rpcbind",1454,8))
LISTEN      0      128                                                     :::80                                                     :::*      users:(("httpd",2095,4),("httpd",2122,4),("httpd",2123,4),("httpd",2124,4),("httpd",2125,4),("httpd",2126,4),("httpd",2127,4),("httpd",2128,4),("httpd",2129,4),("httpd",2130,4),("httpd",3148,4),("httpd",4383,4),("httpd",4716,4))
LISTEN      0      128                                                     :::47316                                                  :::*      users:(("rpc.statd",1525,11))
LISTEN      0      128                                                      *:51796                                                   *:*      users:(("rpc.statd",1525,9))
LISTEN      0      128                                                     :::22                                                     :::*      users:(("sshd",1957,4))
LISTEN      0      128                                                      *:22                                                      *:*      users:(("sshd",1957,3))
LISTEN      0      128                                              127.0.0.1:631                                                     *:*      users:(("cupsd",1580,7))
LISTEN      0      128                                                    ::1:631                                                    :::*      users:(("cupsd",1580,6))
LISTEN      0      100                                                    ::1:25                                                     :::*      users:(("master",2054,13))
LISTEN      0      100                                              127.0.0.1:25                                                      *:*      users:(("master",2054,12))
LISTEN      0      128                                                     :::443                                                    :::*      users:(("httpd",2095,6),("httpd",2122,6),("httpd",2123,6),("httpd",2124,6),("httpd",2125,6),("httpd",2126,6),("httpd",2127,6),("httpd",2128,6),("httpd",2129,6),("httpd",2130,6),("httpd",3148,6),("httpd",4383,6),("httpd",4716,6))
[root@puppet ~]#
```

Comment: Please post the output of `netstat -lptn` and `iptables -nvL` on the Linux VM with the nonworking SSH.

Comment: Shall do, I am in office and once I head, I shall do and paste the response. What I did observer last night is once I kill the sshd daemon and reboot then I can do ssh to not working box. This is just weird...

Comment: Couldn't reply so edited my original post with the output you requested.

Comment: You forgot the output of `ss -lntp`  which is the modern version of `netstat -lntp`.

Comment: Added. There must be something which is causing me for not to do ssh. This is also showing CRITICAL in nagios as connection_refused. Need to investigate what is happening. I believe something to do with networking. But I don't know in detail what is the root cause.

Comment: Is  this confirmed to be an issue that affects only incoming SSH connections?  Can you SSH out?  Can you ping?  Re-check/verify the NIC type in the virtual machine software.

Comment: Yes it does works. please check my previous notes/comments.